# Select records that are not repeated reversely in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Suppose we have a simple table for pairs of users with two columns: user1 and user2. Further, suppose that some pairs appear twice (in a reversed order) and some don't. So, for instance, the pair (1,2) appears in a record where (user1=1 and user2=2) and in another record where (user1=2 and user2=1), while the pair (1,3) appears only once as (user1=1 and user2=3).

I want to write a query that returns all pairs but excludes duplications, meaning that the returned query has each pair appear exactly once. Thus, for the above example, the pair (1,2) should appear only as either (user1=1 and user2=2) or as (user1=2 and user2=1) but not both.

What is the easiest way to achieve this in postgre sql?

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is:

```
select user1, user2
from t
where user1 < user2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.user1 = t1.user2 and t2.user2 = t1.user1
                 );
```

The first condition returns all rows where `user1 < user2`.  The second returns all rows where there is only one pair -- but because this is all in the same `where`, a single pair meeting the first condition is only returned once.

Comment: Well, with the 'WHERE user1<user2', we would be filtering out a pair like (10,2) that might appear only once as user1=10 and user2=2. So, could you correct this? And also, could you elaborate on how the rest solves the problem, if it does? Thanks a lot!